# Serialising data in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql

I tried to prototype some sort of generic serialise function in MySQL which I want to use in several triggers for storing the current state of a table row into another table.

The goal is a string with key value pairs of the data, e.g.

```
id: 3; name: doe; surname: john; age: 25;
```

whereas the keys are the names of the table columns.

So far, I came up with this:

```
delimiter //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SELECTOR //
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECTOR(
    col_name varchar(255), 
    tbl_name varchar(255),
    id integer,
    out result text
)
BEGIN

    set @q = CONCAT('SELECT ', col_name, ' FROM ', tbl_name, ' WHERE id = ', id );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @q;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARe stmt;

END; //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS SERIALISE  //
CREATE FUNCTION SERIALISE(tbl VARCHAR(255), id integer) RETURNS text
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INTEGER;
    DECLARE i INTEGER;
    DECLARE col_name varchar(255);
    DECLARE result varchar(255) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE value text;

    DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = tbl
        ORDER BY ordinal_position;


    open col_names;
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;

    SET i = 1;
    the_loop: LOOP

        IF i > num_rows THEN
            CLOSE col_names;
            LEAVE the_loop;
        END IF;

        FETCH col_names
        INTO col_name;

        call SELECTOR(col_name, tbl, id, value);

            // here the value would be concated as well
        SET result = CONCAT(result, col_name, ", ");

        SET i = i + 1;
    END LOOP the_loop;

    return result;
END; //
```

Sadly, dynamic SQL is not allowed in functions or trigger, so the SELECTOR procedure does not work.

Does anybody have some hints how I could achieve my goal, or is it truly impossible?

Comment: Do that in application. Really - SQL isn't thing to deal with serialization. It's complex thing in common case and logic should be placed to where it belongs - application. DB should be used for just storing data (and avoid any other functionality there as long as possible)

Comment: I see your point. The thing is, I can't solve it generically in the application. Instead, everywhere where data is changed in the code it must be rewritten to insert the data in the log. This may lead to programming mistakes or it might just get forgotten.

Comment: You'll need to apply the corresponding application pattern then. For example, adapter to work with DBMS and define desired actions with raw data there. Whole application must use this and only this method to work with DBMS, thus, all modification would be done in application on the fly. This won't work with legacy code (without refactoring) of course - because, obviously, some existing logic of working with DBMS will cause troubles